# Passing Data to MainActivity after receiving notification with AppNotificationReceiver

Tags: java, android

Receiving a notification in NotificationReceiver class that includes my data string. However, when trying to pass that string to a class in MainActivity I'm not getting any data. No errors either.

NotificationReceiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, AppNotification notification) {
        Toast.makeText(context, notification.payload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (notification.appEvent.equals(NOTIFICATION_ACTION)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("orderId", notification.payload);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Hitting New Intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Order Received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        new OrderAsyncTask().execute(intent.getStringExtra("orderId"));
    }
```

The expected result is to receive my string in either onHandleIntent or onNewIntent

**UPDATED**
MainActivity Class Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_PAYLOAD = "payload";
    public String orderId = null;

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        onNewIntent(intent.getStringExtra("orderId"));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        onNewIntent(intent.getStringExtra("orderId"));

    }

    public void onNewIntent(String orderId) {

        if(orderId != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "List order " + orderId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you are trying to get the caller intent on are not overridden from anything. I suggest you to try getting the intent and processing data on activity's onCreate method

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
new OrderAsyncTask().execute(intent.getStringExtra("orderId"));
```

Also suggest you to change

```
public String orderId = null;
```

into

```
public String mOrderId = null;
```

Or just remove it because it might get mixed up with other orderId variable on your

```
onHandleIntent(String orderId)
```

method

Edit: Since you want to pass data from notification receiver to your mainActivity while  the activity is running, I would suggest you to register the receiver inside your MainActivity

Please see this link, example of such design with Clover SDK https://github.com/clover/clover-android-sdk/blob/master/clover-android-sdk-examples/src/main/java/com/clover/android/sdk/examples/AppNotificationTestActivity.java

From the code:

```
private String orderId;
private AppNotificationReceiver receiver = new 
AppNotificationReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, AppNotification notification) {
  log("Received " + notification);
orderId = notification.payload();
}
};

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//Register the receiver to your mainActivity
receiver.register(this);

}

  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
receiver.unregister();
}
```

You can directly get orderId into your MainActivity like this

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I move this to the onCreate method my application keeps shutting down. Unfortunately, I do not have error codes as this is running on a Clover POS device but can confirm that as soon as I reference the Activity it shuts down when the notification is sent.

Comment: Can you please share us the complete MainActivity code?

Comment: Updated it on the main question.

Comment: please see edited answer and check if it fixes the problem

Comment: I assume you want to send data to your mainActivity while the activity is running. If so, this code is completely wrong. If thats the case I will update my answer again

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, after implementing this, I'm not receiving the Notification at all anymore.

Comment: I ended up passing this to a new activity and the first answer you provided worked.

Comment: glad it helped!